# SSIS - Import multiple sql views as tables periodically

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssas, sql-server-2014

I'm fairly new to SQL Server management and am currently looking in to building a solution with SSIS.
My question will be mostly about "is my logic correct" and some smaller things about what the best practice would be.

But let me paint you a picture to start!

I have an application which provides me with DB Views, to offload the stress on that database I would like to transfer the data of these views periodically to a secondary database/different instance on which I can then also set more specific permissions/transformations/other views build on that data. My views initially provided are pretty much fixed in how I can get them.

After some reading it looked to me that the way to go was to use SSIS. I started building my package and used the "SSIS Import and Export wizard" to do an initial transfer.

Now for my first question, would this be the proper way to transfer the data and is SSIS the right tool for the job?

Secondly, I noticed that the wizard made multiple SQL Preperation tasks and Data flow tasks.
For me it would seem logical to split each view that becomes a table in to a seperate SQL Preperation Task and a seperate Data flow task just to keep a clear picture and as much control as possible. While that would take some time to set up (>100 views/tables) it seems cleaner than how the wizard did it by just grouping some of them together.

Also, since the preperation tasks already create tables these fail when executed a 2nd time as they already exist. Is there a quick workarround for this besides adding a IFEXISTS clause to each query?

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated or hints towards a better solution if I'm approaching this completly from the wrong direction.
The idea is to later on add some SSAS to the system and provide some data analytics on these tables/data as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I misformulated that sentence. I'm creating multiple tables from multiple source views, each view has completely different columns/data types but they simply come from the same source database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are transferring the data to a different instance then SSIS is probably your best bet.  Your next question is to work out whether you want to import all the data each time or just the new/updated items.

If you are exporting all the data every time, this is much simpler and assumig you have a suitable maintenance window (such as overnight) that you can complete the process in without affecting your end users, you can get away with simply truncating the data and re-loading.  This obviously has consequences related to increased data transfer volumes.

If you want to only export the new/updated data, you will now need to work out whether or not you can actually work out which rows are new or different without simply comparing them all to what you have in your secondary database.  Ideally your source tables will have a reliable `LastUpdateDate` column or better yet a `rowversion` column, using which you can export all rows with a more recent value than can be seen in the corresponding table in your secondary instance.

There is a lot of reading to be done regarding the updates only route, for which I would strongly suggest you [avoid the Slowly Changing Dimension transformation like the plague](https://benefic.net/ssis-alternatives-to-the-scd-transform/).

You are also right in thinking that there is a lot of repetitive tasks when you want to do simple operations across a large number of similar objects, such as adding that `ifexists` to the table creation in your post.  The best way to tackle this I have found is to learn how to use [Biml](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/biml/info) to automate the repetitive tasks based on metadata.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, does that mean that splitting up each prep task and dataflow task for each table makes sense/is a best practice? Or combining them makes more sense?

Comment: @DirkR.  I would say a lot of that comes down to personal preference and the needs of your solution.  Personally I prefer to extract everything and then do the transformations where possible to keep things simple, though this is not always possible or sensible depending on your situation.  I would recommend designing a a few ways of doing what you want to do and then choosing the one that looks best suited.  That way you will also force yourself to look at different approaches and therefore learn more.

Comment: Well to start it would basicly be: take data from view A (DB1) and dump it in to table A (DB2), take data from view B (DB1) and dump it in table B (DB2) and then schedule a package to update/replace the data in the frequency that we will decide afterwards. (so no transformations just yet) The thing is that I'm fairly new to SSIS and I have a feeling that if I set this up incorrectly now it will haunt me forever :) Taking a course as well on it but always nice to hear from someone that actually worked with it and has real life experience.

Comment: @DirkR.  That is pretty much as simple as it gets, so don't worry too much or try to overthink it.  As I said in my answer the first question is *do you have a maintenance window in which you can run the update?*  If so, you can just transfer the data into a staging environment on `DB2` and if successful, `truncate` the destination tables and load from staging.  If not, you will need to think about how you can update the data with as little impact on your users as possible.